# Ember.js bind-attr: is the guide wrong or am I doing it wrong

Tags: ember.js

According to the [guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-attributes/) (which is always risky to go by it seems) I believe the following should work.

#### Template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="slideToggle">
    {{#if checked}}        
        <div class="slideToggle">
    {{else}}
        <div class="slideToggle off">
    {{/if}}
        <span {{bind-attr on=onText}} {{bind-attr off=offText}}>
          {{#if checked}} {{onText}} {{else}}{{offText}}{{/if}}
        </span>
    </div>
    {{input type="checkbox" class="hidden" name=name }}
    <label for={{bind-attr name=name}}>{{labelText}}</label>
</script>
```

#### View

```
App.slideToggle = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName:   'slideToggle'
,   onText      :   'on'
,   offText     :   'off'
,   labelText   :   ''
,   classNames  :   ['slideToggleWrapper']
,   name        :   ''
,   checked     :   false
});
```

This View is for use within other templates, currently like so:

#### Usage (includeJobs is currently false)

```
{{view App.slideToggle name="includeJobs" labelText="Jobs" checked=includeJobs}}
```

#### Expected HTML (only the most pertinent parts)

```
<span on="on" off="off">off</span>
<label for="includeJobs">Jobs</label>
```

#### What I actually get for data binding (only the unexpected part)

```
<span data-bindattr-6="6" data-bindattr-7="7"></span>
<label data-bindattr-8="8">[script placeholder but no text]</label>
```

This really doesn't work because I need the actual attribute names for script logic used in the `action` handler, and also because obviously the `for` property of a `<label>` won't work if it is named something like `data-bindattr-8` Furthermore, my `{{labelText}}` doesn't output at all!

**UPDATE : Edited for clarity.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only use one bind-attr per element

`{{bind-attr on='onText' off='offText'}}`

And your label should be like this

`<label {{bind-attr for='name'}}>`

the quotes aren't necessary, it'll work both ways:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uDAXayA/2/edit

Comment: Thanks, I'd caught the label error a moment ago but I didn't realize I could only use bind-attr once.